# WebGL light source and cube map rotate with the viewer

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl, shader

I was trying to implement lighting and environment mapping in WebGL.
I got this weird bug that my light source and cube map rotate with my eye position. For example, when I "fly" to the back of my object I can still see the specular reflection and the front of my cube map...
This is the code for calculating the reflection vector..

```
    vec4 N = invertMVM*vNormal;
    R = reflect(eyePos.xyz, N.xyz);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it..
Using the modleViewMat to transform the reflection vector works.